# Moment Timezone not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I might be doing something silly here. But essentially, the time in Lisbon right now is 12:27 PM

but the following returns 14:27 (EU central time)

```
  const time = moment.tz("Europe/Lisbon")
  const timeZone = "Europe/Lisbon"
  const format = "'HH[:]mm'"
  const startMoment = moment.tz(item.startTime, format, timeZone); 
  const endMoment = moment(item.endTime, format, timeZone); 
  return time.isBetween(startMoment, endMoment);
```

I tried several combinations and I get the wrong answer everytime. For example if I set timeZone to be "Europe/Warsaw" it returns 15:27 whereas it should be 13:27.

EDIT:  `const currentTime = moment().tz("Europe/London").format()` returns the correct time for London. However, the return statement `moment(currentTime).isBetween(startMoment, endMoment)` still reads "moment(correntTime)" as the local time.

Comment: so, item.startTime and item.endTime are regular `Date` objects? how does that code return a time anyway ... shouldn't it be returning a boolean ... `.isBetween` sounds like it returns true or false

Comment: item.startTime and item.endTime are in the given Timezone right (e.g. Europe/Lisbon)?

Comment: `const endMoment = moment(item.endTime, format, timeZone); ` .... missing a `.tz` there?

Comment: @JaromadaX no. Sorry, the "item.endtime" is already a formatted time and it doesn't need to be converted. Its only the return that doesn't work properly and time.isBetween = wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

`isBetween` return boolean . And `isBetween` runs on date object. You are trying to run on `time zone` object. which is different from date object

```js
    const time = moment.tz("Europe/Lisbon")
    const timeZone = "Europe/Lisbon"
    const format = "'HH[:]mm'"
    const startMoment = moment().subtract(8, 'months').tz(timeZone).format(); 
    const endMoment = moment(new Date()).tz(timeZone).format() ; 
    console.log("startMoment",startMoment)
    console.log("endMoment",endMoment)
    console.log(moment.tz(new Date(),"Europe/Lisbon").format())
    console.log(moment('2020-09-30').isBetween(startMoment, endMoment));
```

```html
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks but the "item.startTime" is irrelevant to the question. It's a formatted time string and it works as it should. My formatting was wrong, i can get the correct result by console logging console.log(moment.tz(new Date(),"Europe/Lisbon").format(format)) but Im not sure how to use that with the inBetween function

Comment: I have updated my answer can you check again. Does that answer your problem?

Comment: ```const currentTime = moment.tz(new Date(),"Europe/Lisbon,").format()``` and returning ```      return moment(currentTime).isBetween(startMoment, endMoment)``` the moment(currentTime) still doesn't give the expected result as currentTime is still wrong. It shows 13:08 instead of 14:08.

Comment: Its because you added extra comma `,` which make `.tz` invalid. Try this: `const currentTime = moment.tz(new Date(),"Europe/Lisbon").format()
` **note** there is no comma after `Lisbon`

Comment: thanks! But I've spotted that, check out the edit above. It's working fine until I try to use isBetween with the currentTime. return moment(currentTime).isBetween(startMoment, endMoment) === just localTime instead of western currentTime.isBetween(startMoment, endMoment) === error